# RegEx IP range class A network

Tags: regex, filter, grep, range

I am trying to filter IP Range, which partially works as it also includes a higher range.

I need only the range from `10.0.0.1` until `10.20.0.254`.

The problem is that it also matches the network `10.x.120.x`.

Here is the syntax I used:

```
egrep '10.([0-9]{1,3}).([0-1]|[0-9]|20).([0-9]{1,3})'
```

Example:

```
echo '10.2.120.0' | egrep '10.([0-9]{1,3}).([0-1]|[0-9]|20).([0-9]{1,3})'
```

It also prints undesirable IPs. I would like to limit it to `10.x.20.x`.

Comment: Please include few valid and invalid IPs

Comment: Use the https://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/ipregex service, `^10\.((0\.){2}([1-9]|[1-9]\d|[12]\d\d)|0\.([1-9]|[1-9]\d|[12]\d\d)\.([1-9]?\d|[12]\d\d)|20\.0\.([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4])|([1-9]|1\d)(\.([1-9]?\d|[12]\d\d)){2})$`

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
10\.(?:[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]?|20)\.0\.(?:25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]|1[1-9]|[1-9])
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/MXduKN/1)

With GNU `grep` it would be:

```
grep -oP '10\.(?:[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]?|20)\.0\.(?:25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]|1[1-9]|[1-9])' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
10\.(?:[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]?|20)\.0\.                         
##Matching 10 dot and range from 0 to 20 here, followed by 0. here.
(?:25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]|1[1-9]|[1-9])  
##Matching from 1 to 254 range here in a non-capturing group.
```

Comment: Just tested. But it does not trigger even the initial IP (10.2.20.0). echo '10.2.20.0' | egrep '^10\.(?:[0-1][0-9]?|20)\.0\.(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-4]))$'  which it should still.

Comment: @Joe, I just tested with `grep`'s `-oP` option like: `grep -oP '^10\.(?:[0-1][0-9]?|20)\.0\.(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-4]))$'  Input_file` run fine for me, let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: @Joe, try `grep -oP '10\.(?:[0-1][0-9]?|20)\.0\.(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-4]))' Input_file` try this one once?

Comment: It match only of IP range of 10.19.0.x, however anything below such as 10.18.0.x does not seems to work.

Comment: @Joe, Could you please check my updated link and update code, let me know how it goes. In Online demo I have added more samples to check this code, let me know how it goes, thank you.